# How to set output in a variable from conditional statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I make a condition with Else-If to print a line like [You got A+, You got D]. Now I want to store one valid output line in a variable outside the condition.

```
var gradeMark = Math.round(totalNumber / 6);

//Generate grade mark
if (gradeMark >= 80) {
    console.log("You got A+");
} else if (gradeMark >= 70) {
    console.log("You got A");
}....
.....
else if (gradeMark >= 0) {
    console.log("You got F");
} else {
    console.log("It's not valid mark");
}

//Getting grading mark
var validGradeMark =
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Set your `validGradeMark`  before if statement fill it inside,, and use later...

Comment: I need //It's not valid mark or valid output 
which will be printed after true condition as a variable.

Comment: I think you missing some basics: https://jsfiddle.net/ikiK_Cro/wjotkbs2/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use defining variable instead of console log and it is out of condition now.

```
let gradeMark = Math.round(totalNumber / 6);
let validGradeMark;

// Generate grade mark
if (gradeMark >= 80) {
   validGradeMark = "You got A+";
} else if (gradeMark >= 70) {
   validGradeMark = "You got A";
}....
.....
else if (gradeMark >= 0) {
   validGradeMark = "You got F";
} else {
   validGradeMark = "It's not valid mark";
}

// Getting grading mark
console.log(validGradeMark);
```